# CSS - Cropping Image Height To Match Text Length

Tags: css, crop

I've got 2 things sharing section - a header comprised of text, and an imaged floated to its right. I'd like the image width to always be 308px, and its height to crop according to the needs of the text length. I'm not interested in setting a fixed height for .location, as content length may change down the line. How can this be done? (Thank you!)

The HTML:

```
<section class="location">
<img src="http://evinwolverton.com/img/disc.jpg">
<header>
    <h2>This Is A Headline</h2>
    Etiam porta sem malesuada magna<br/> 
        Mollis euismod. Duis mollis<br/>
        Est non commodo luctus, nisi erat<br/>
        Porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio<br/>
        Sem nec elit.
</header>
 </section>
```

The CSS:

```
.location {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 620px;
    color: #666;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.location header {
    float: left;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 258px;
}

.location h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #333;
}   

.location img {
    float: right;
    width: 308px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution to using a background image, if you want this to be an actual `<img>` tag would be to position `.location` relative, keep the overflow hidden on here & give the image an absolute position.
You may need to give some margin-right on the text holder too, to ensure it doesn't go behind the image.

```
.location {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.location img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting! How would you constrain the image dimensions with this technique?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a `background-image` aligned to the right-top corner with `no-repeat`.

Comment: Man, I wish I could do this, but it must be an img with an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your image does not need to be an `img` tag, you could apply it as a background image to your header. But I'm assuming that's not the case.

Try:

```
.location img {
  position:absolute;
  clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

[EDIT]

Sorry, try `clip: rect(0px, 308px, 100%, 0px);` and I'm pretty sure you will need to have the image floated **inside** your header.

Comment: Curious. Thank you! The image does need to be an img wrapped in an anchor tag.